# Show Snowfall (or other grafics) just in Specific Month

Tags: android, android-studio

i have the following code inserted in my app:

[JetradarMobile/android-snowfall](https://github.com/JetradarMobile/android-snowfall)

How to make this effect only active in December?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what language you are using, but all of them have packages that let you check the current date.
Assuming you are using Java for you android app, you can get the current date from the device and check if it's December like this:

````
import java.time.LocalDateTime;   

public class yourClass{

     public static void main(String []args){
        int month = LocalDateTime.now().getMonthValue();
        if (month == 12){
            System.out.println("It's December");
            //Your animation code goes here
        }
     }
}```
````